# Javascript onClick functions not working

Tags: javascript

I've got this money management system that I'm trying to write, and It's not working correctly.  The money is printed in the top right, but when I click on the buttons to change the value, it does not work.

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
<div id="money_count">$$MONEY$$</div>
<br>
<div id="items">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#">$12.19</a>
            </td>
            <td><a href="#">$15.00</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#">$24.99</a>
            </td>
            <td><a href="#">$35.50</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content {
font-family:Helvetica;
width:500px;
box-shadow:0px 0px 10px 0px #AAA;
top:30px;
margin:0px auto;
margin-top:40px;
padding:10px 20px;
border:dashed 2px #888;
}
#money_count {
    color:#0F0;
    padding:5px;
    text-shadow:0px 0px 1px #333;
    margin-right:0;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-top:6px;
    width:100px;
    text-align:center;
}

table, th td {
    border:ridge 3px #AAA;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 6px 0px #AAA;
}
table {
    width:400px;
    margin-left:50px;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-bottom:50px;
}
td {
    padding:4px;
    background-color:#CCC;
    text-align:center;
}
a, td {
    color:black;
    text-decoration:none;
    width:auto;
    height:100px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var money = 500.27 - 0.27;
var moneyElement = document.getElementById("money_count");
moneyElement.innerHTML = money;

function updateMoney() {
    moneyElement.innerHTML = money;
}

function subtractMoney(amount) {
    money -= amount;
    updateMoney();
}
```

any ideas as to why this doesn't update the money value in the top right?

Comment: Where is the onclick event?

Comment: Your code doesnot contain any onclick events..

Comment: As an aside, you shouldn't really use Javascript floats as money values. Maybe this could help - http://josscrowcroft.github.io/accounting.js/.

Comment: Consider using jQuery, it makes your life much easier

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the event listeners to the elements:

`document.getElementById('button_id').addEventListener('onclick', updateMoney, false)`